# Can you use the isolation forest algorithm on large sample sizes?

Tags: python, algorithm, machine-learning, scikit-learn, sampling

I've been using the scikit learn `sklearn.ensemble.IsolationForest` implementation of the isolation forest  to detect anomalies in my datasets that range from 100s of rows to millions of rows worth of data. It seems to be working well and I've overridden the `max_samples` to a very large integer to handle some of my larger datasets (essentially not using sub-sampling). I noticed that the [original paper](https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/4781136)  states that larger sample sizes create risk of swamping and masking.

Is it okay to use the isolation forest on large sample sizes if it seems to be working okay? I tried training with a smaller `max_samples` and the testing produced too many anomalies. My data has really started to grow and I'm wondering if a different anomaly detection algorithm would be better for such a large sample size.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Citing the original paper:

> The isolation characteristic of iTrees enables them to build partial
> models and exploit sub-sampling to an extent that is not feasible in
> existing methods. Since a large part of an iTree that isolates normal
> points is not needed for anomaly detection; **it does not need to be
> constructed**. A small sample size produces better iTrees because the
> swamping and masking effects are reduced.

From you question, I have a feeling that you confuse between the size of the dataset, and the size of the sample you take from it to construct iTree. The Isolation forest can handle very large datasets. It works better when it samples them.

The original paper discusses it in chapter 3:

> The data set has two anomaly clusters located close to one large
> cluster of normal points at the centre. There are interfering normal
> points surrounding the anomaly clusters, and the anomaly clusters are
> denser than normal points in this sample of 4096 instances. Figure
> 4(b) shows a sub-sample of 128 instances of the original data. The
> anomalies clusters are clearly identifiable in the sub-sample.
> Those normal instances surrounding the two anomaly clusters have been
> cleared out, and the size of anomaly clusters becomes smaller which
> makes them easier to identify. When using the entire sample, iForest
> reports an AUC of 0.67. When using a sub-sampling size of 128, iForest
> achieves an AUC of 0.91.

[image]

Isolation forest is not a perfect algorithm and needs parameter tuning for your specific data. It might even perform poorly on some datasets. If you wish to consider other methods, [Local Outlier Factor](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/outlier_detection.html#local-outlier-factor) is also included in `sklearn`. You may also combine several methods (ensemble).

Here you can find a nice [comparison](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/miscellaneous/plot_anomaly_comparison.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-miscellaneous-plot-anomaly-comparison-py) of different methods.

Comment: Thanks @igrinis. I understand the difference between the size of a dataset and the size of the sample you take from it to contruct the iTree. The default number of samples in the sklearn implementation is 256. Using the default for my dataset that has over 1 million rows produced innaccurate results. Overriding max_samples to use the whole dataset seemed to produce much better results.  
I can't use the Local Outlier Factor method because it has no predict method and I need to detect anomalies on historical data.  
Is it bad practice to override max_samples or is this okay?

Comment: I've also some of the other sklearn methods you listed and the isolation forest seems to be most accurate.

Comment: As I mentioned previously, Isolation forest as any other algorithm needs finding best parameters to fit your data. If for your data works best setting sample size 100k or taking 20% of the whole data set - it is perfectly fine. That is exact reason the function provided you the ability to change the default parameters.The default values were set for some other data, and most probably do not suit your data. Do not be afraid to experiment. The true success measure is only your final results.